# How to get sleep data in my ionic app from google fit/android as sleep?

Tags: ionic3, healthkit, google-fit, fitbit

I am new to ionic framework, So the other day I tried to get data from google fit and I am able to get steps and calories but I am not able to get sleep data,So my question is is there any way I can get sleep data in my ionic app(either from google fit or any other android application).
I already checked [this ionic Cordova site](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health)

Here is the code to get walking data but don't know about sleep

```
    loadWalking(){
    console.log("####*******  Load Health data entered");
var fromDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var toDate = new Date();
if (days > 0) {
  console.log("#### Load health calling for " + days + " days");
  this.health.query({
    startDate: fromDate, //  days ago
    endDate: toDate, // now
    dataType: 'steps'
  }).then(res => {
    // var data = res;
    // if(res.length>0)
    // alert("Load Health Data"+JSON.stringify(res));

    console.log("Walking data from API"+JSON.stringify(res));



    this.storage.get('my-json').then((val) => {
      this.calculateTodayStep(res);


      if(val==null || JSON.stringify(val) != JSON.stringify(res)){
        console.log("not equal");
        this.storage.set('my-json', res);
        this.saveToDB(res);
        console.log("*************6.load HEALTH DATA RESULT:::" + JSON.stringify(res)); //this.activity=res.value; 
      }else{

        console.log("data=>"+val);
        console.log("Json data=>"+JSON.stringify(val));       
        console.log("data are equal");

      }

    });


  })
    .catch(e => {
      // alert("Health QUERY" + JSON.stringify(e));
      console.log("************ 5.HEALTH steps DATA ERROR" + e);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please show how you are successfully getting steps and calories, how you are trying to get sleep data, and describe what happens instead of getting the sleep data.

Comment: Hey Andy,I updated..please help if you know